GCP Internal UDP Loadbalancer for UD netflows
I try to setup a internal loadblancer with 2 instances in the gcp-environment, which handles Netflow UDP-packets.
Behind this LB are some flow-collectors, which should get all (normal and fragmented) flow packets from a specific netflow-device(e.g a router).
These flow packets are send every 1 second from some network devices. It is a permanent unidirectional-stream. (Everytime same source-ip, dest-ip, source-port and dest-port)...not to forget the udp-fragments, which do not have a port.
So far this is working well, but I have a problem, if an instance of the LB pool is going unhealthy and healthy again. In this fallback-situation the traffic is not coming back to the "new" healthy instance. Even If I reboot this instance, the "old" traffic is not switched.
I try to follow the "UDP fragmentation"-section here: Google-LB UDP
Is there any way to tell gcp that if the instance is coming back, to recalculate the session affinity (tracking) table?
Please have a look here:
resource "google_compute_instance_group" "ndr_prod_all" {
      provider    = google-beta
      name        = "ndr-prod-all"
      instances   = [for vm in google_compute_instance.cisco-ndr-ona-sensor : vm.id]
      zone        = local.zone
    }
    
    # Create a health check
    resource "google_compute_health_check" "ndr_health_check" {
      provider = google-beta
      name               = "ndr-health-check"
      tcp_health_check {
        port              = 5000
        response = "OK"
      }
    }
    
    # Create a backend service
    resource "google_compute_region_backend_service" "ndr_prod_all" {
      provider = google-beta
      name          = "ndr-prod-all"
      protocol      = "UDP"
      load_balancing_scheme = "INTERNAL"
      session_affinity = "CLIENT_IP"
      connection_tracking_policy {
        tracking_mode = "PER_SESSION"
      }
      backend {
        group = google_compute_instance_group.ndr_prod_all.self_link
      }
      region = local.region
      
      health_checks = [google_compute_health_check.ndr_health_check.self_link]
    }
    
    # Create a forwarding rule
    resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "ndr_prod_all_forwarding_rule" {
      provider = google-beta
      
      name        = "ndr-prod-all-forwarding-rule"
      load_balancing_scheme = "INTERNAL"
      ip_protocol = "UDP"
      region = local.region
      backend_service = google_compute_region_backend_service.ndr_prod_all.self_link
    
      ip_address = "10.10.10.10"
    
      network =    "projects/xxxx/global/networks/on-prem-connectivity"
      subnetwork = "projects/xxxx/regions/${local.region}/subnetworks/${local.subnetwork}"
      all_ports = true
    }

